# Replace Values in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've looked around at replacing values in SQL and I have found ISNULL as a potential solution, but am running into Syntax Errors for whatever reason. I believe it's because I am combining this with another REPLACE() at the same time.

My data has both random 1's and NULL's that I'd like to default to zero. The following code works for removing the 1's, but I can't get the second line to work.... Any ideas why?

```
REPLACE(Credit,1, 0) Credit
```

Not working:

```
ISNULL(REPLACE(Credit,1, 0),0) Credit
```

Query:

```
 SELECT ID, Name, Class,
 REPLACE(REPLACE(Gender,'M', 'Male'), 'F', 'Female') Gender,
 REPLACE(Credit,1,0) Credit
 FROM mySQL
 WHERE State = 'MO'
```

Comment: `REPLACE(Credit,1, 0)` will convert `100` to `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should first check for `NULL` values and then use `replace()`

```
REPLACE(ISNULL(Credit, 0),1, 0) Credit
```

OR

```
REPLACE(COALESCE(Credit, 0),1, 0) Credit
```

For **SQLLite** use the following

```
IFNULL(mycolumn, 0)
```

more information [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull).

Comment: I am still getting red underlines with both of these.... Works totally fine without the ISNULL, and when I copy/paste this in directly it gives me red. Thoughts?

Comment: @RCarmody could you please post your full query and also which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: I am using SQLite Studio... Query posted in a moment